Can we get some automated filtering of answers that are entirely plagiarized from code of other answers to the same question?
On a bit of a whim I've spent some time on and off during the past couple of weeks looking through the New Answers to Old Questions feed, and I have noticed a recurring pattern of plagiarism.  A few times each day, an answer is posted that consists entirely of multiple lines of code copied from some other answer to the same question without attribution.  Can some sort of automated filter be implemented that blocks such trivially plagiarized answers?
Adding some details, the pattern I have noticed is:

A new answer to an old question.

By a 1-rep account.

Consisting entirely of multiple lines of code with no explanatory text.

That is copied exactly (including matching case) from some code block in another answer to the same question with no attribution.

Frequently the formatting is copied also, making the copying quite obvious: Examples:

Toggle Bootstrap button text on button click?,
Stop pasting html style in a contenteditable div only paste the plain text,
Display a loading bar before the entire page is loaded,
fullcalendar timegridweek don't show events time properly,
Issues implementing SHA256 hash, then pbkdf2Sync and finally cipher with AES-256-cbc - c# to Nodejs,
Overlay image on div
(subsequently edited to change <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null --> to <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babe2: null -->)
PDF file to be displayed on the dialog modal via bootstrap,


But sometimes the formatting is not copied so the posts look quite different.  Examples:

How to count Total Downline , Give me any Idea (MLM project),
Chrome Extension get selected text,


Occasionally code is copied from multiple answers:  Examples:

Change background color randomly and automatically after 1 second,


Or the code is truncated.  Examples:

How to scrape football week results.



One or two plagiarized answers per day doesn't sound like a lot, but that's just what I noticed by checking the NATO feed for a few hours on several days in the past couple weeks.  Assuming my sample was random we're talking hundreds per year.  It's enough that I can manually raise "Plagiarism" flags faster than mods seem to be handling them.  And while reviewers in the "Late Answers" queue are, according to this answer to Is a plagiarism audit justified?, supposed to check for internal plagiarism:

the Late Answers queue is a bit different from others insofar as checking for internal plagiarism (i.e. copies of other answers to the same question) should (IMHO) be an inherent part of the review process.

it doesn't seem to be working.
Could we implement some automated way to block such answers or screen them out?  And if so, what should it be?  I'm not sure that "better onboarding" would be the solution here, such trivially obviously copied answers border on being abusive.  If we warn the poster about their plagiarism while they are creating their post, then (assuming they are not bots) they will probably just tweak the post a little, so maybe a plagiarism flag should be automatically raised instead?

...How many different users do you see doing this?

@KarlKnechtel - Each copied answer is from a different account.  All except one are 1-rep accounts.  After double-checking I realized one had a 21-rep.  That one only copied two lines so it might have been a mistake by that user.  I'll remove the 21-rep answer from my list.

Weird. Maybe someone is trying to establish a farm of "legitimate" accounts for future spamming or something like that.

Or for the Review Queues ('First Answers' / 'Late Answers'), we could use a 'Delete'/Not allow/Close reason as "Late Answer, only copy of some older Answer in the same Thread, does not add any new Info", or stg like that...

@KarlKnechtel - there are around 1.46 billion English speakers in the world.  Could just be that every day, one or two out of a billion of 'em decides to start padding their fake resume with a real Stack Overflow account containing fake answers.

The (main?) purpose of the 'Late Answers' Review Queue should be to prevent that kind of Answers...!

Ideally, I'd much rather such a feature find plagiarism from any other answer on the site, as (perhaps unsurprisingly) Stack Overflow is a very frequent source for plagiarized material posted to Stack Overflow.  It is usually not from the same question, though (although that is, as you demonstrate, surprisingly common).

@RyanM, hum..., my experience is also just like OP's, Surf Answers like I call them (nearly) always come from the same Thread. What you describe is more the Answerer did a little bit of search/research, on such a basic (recent) Question that the Question actually is a Duplicate. (And should be closed as such...) OP is rather talking about "older" Questions with already 10's or 100's of UV's and [5-25+] Answers already..., as I understand...

"Can some sort of automated filter be implemented that blocks such trivially plagiarized answers?" - another "Can" question :) Will it be implemented is the follow up question. The one that will perpetually disappoint. Nice effort, but I think it is more productive if people reviewing can keep more of an eye out for it.

@Gimby - the problem with that is that the "Late answers" review queue does not show the other answers, meaning the reviewer has to open the question in another tab or window and thread through them all (and for older questions there might be multiple pages to read through).  If we want people to check for duplicates in that queue, the Stack Exchange software need to show them the possible duplicates on the review page itself.

Re "Consisting entirely of multiple lines of code with no explanatory text.": AKA code dumps. Not for this kind of plagiarism, but spot check of code dumps often reveal they are totally bogus answers. Suggesting they are (often) the result of blind copying from somewhere, e.g., blind copying from a search engine result (without any understanding of it).
